# how to convert a path in NSString to CFURLRef and to FSRef*

Tags: objective-c, file

I need to use several functions requiring CFURLRef and FSRef* and for the moment I just have a path stored in an NSString.
What is the (most efficient) way to perform this conversion?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A path can be easily converted to a CFURL by using NSURL, which it is toll-free bridged with. There is also a CFURL function which will give you a FSRef for it. This code will give you both, given an NSString named thePath.

```
CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
FSRef fileRef;
CFURLGetFSRef(url, &fileRef);
```

If you already have a valid pointer to a `FSRef`, you can pass it to `CFURLGetFSRef` directly.

Comment: Thanks for you quick and efficient answer :)

Comment: for ARC it has to be CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Comment: Does the code actually work? fileRef is not initialized doesn't get set by the call to CFURLGetFSRef either. This might lead to a crash, IMO. The correct use would be to declare "FSRef fileRef" and then pass it as &fileRef

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! I don't know how nobody caught that before, perhaps it was always used by someone who already had a valid pointer to store it in. (fixed)